# Construct object with new type conforming to another type

Tags: typescript, derived-types

I'd like to construct a bunch of different objects that must each conform to a pre-specified type but which themselves each have a type unique to its specific structure. Moreover, I'd like the ability to enforce conformance to the pre-specified type at the place where the object is constructed.

Consider the following code, which converts a structure that defines APIs into the APIs themselves, each of which is statically type-checked:

```js
type ApiTemplate = {
  [funcName: string]: {
    call: (data: any) => void;
    handler: (data: any) => void;
  }
};

const apiConfig1 = /* see below */;
const apiConfig2 = /* see below */;
const apiConfig3 = /* see below */;

function toApi<T extends ApiTemplate>(
  config: T
): { [n in keyof T]: T[n]["call"] } {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(config).map(
      ([funcName, apiDef]) => [funcName, apiDef.call]
    )
  ) as any;
}

const api1 = toApi(apiConfig1);
const api2 = toApi(apiConfig2);
const api3 = toApi(apiConfig3);

api1.func1(2); // statically typed function signature
```

I want to define each `apiConfig*` object in a separate file, and I'd like type static checking available from the editor while coding up the objects. I'd also like the compiler to identify errors within the objects. If I didn't want such type checking, I could just define the APIs as follows:

```js
const apiConfig1 = {
  func1: {
    call: (count: number) => console.log("count", count),
    handler: (data: any) => console.log(data),
  },
  func2: {
    call: (name: string) => console.log(name),
    handler: (data: any) => console.log("string", data),
  },
};
```

However, if there is a mistake in the object construction, such as mispelling 'handler' as 'handle', TypeScript reports the error at the call to `toApi()`, which is not where I want the error.

I tried the following:

```js
const apiConfig1 = (function <T extends ApiTemplate>(): T {
  return {
    func1: {
      call: (count: number) => console.log("count", count),
      handler: (data: any) => console.log(data),
    },
    func2: {
      call: (name: string) => console.log(name),
      handler: (data: any) => console.log("string", data),
    },
  };
})();
```

But I get this error message:

```
Type '{ func1: { call: (count: number) => void; handler: (data: any) => void; };
func2: { call: (name: string) => void; handler: (data: any) => void; }; }'
is not assignable to type 'T'.
  '{ func1: { call: (count: number) => void; handler: (data: any) => void; };
  func2: { call: (name: string) => void; handler: (data: any) => void; }; }'
  is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated
  with a different subtype of constraint 'Template'.ts(2322)
```

And when I tried this:

```js
const apiConfig1 = (function <T>(): T extends ApiTemplate ? T : never {
  return {
    func1: {
      call: (count: number) => console.log("count", count),
      handler: (data: any) => console.log(data),
    },
    func2: {
      call: (name: string) => console.log(name),
      handler: (data: any) => console.log("string", data),
    },
  }
});
```

I get this error message:

```
Type '{ func1: { call: (count: number) => void; handler: (data: any) => void; };
func2: { call: (name: string) => void; handler: (data: any) => void; }; }'
is not assignable to type 'T extends ApiTemplate ? T : never'.ts(2322)
```

Is there a way to do what I want in TypeScript?

NOTE: The following approach eliminates static type-checking from the API that `toApi()` generates because it discards each object's unique type:

```js
const apiConfig1: ApiTemplate = /* ... */;
```

Comment: @kaya3, yes it does! And you posted the link only a few minutes after I already figured this out for myself and posted the answer below. I've spent hours searching the net and SO for the solution today and never saw that post. Thank you!

Comment: I linked to this post as another use case for an open TypeScript feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a simple type annotation:

```
type ApiTemplate = {
  [funcName: string]: {
    call: (data: any) => void;
    handler: (data: any) => void;
  }
};

const apiConfig1: ApiTemplate = {
  func1: {
    call: (count: number) => console.log("count", count),
    handler: (data: any) => console.log(data),
  },
  func2: {
    call: (name: string) => console.log(name),
    handler: (data: any) => console.log("string", data),
  },
};
```

Changing `handler` to `handle` for example shows the error directly where the typo is.

Comment: This eliminates static type checking on my generated APIs. I updated my question to clarify that this isn't going to solve the problem.

Comment: Would leaving `apiConfig1` as is and adding `const apiConfig1_check: ApiTemplate = apiConfig1;` directly below work?

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do this, by writing a function that both asserts the base type of its parameter and returns the original type of the parameter:

```js
function assertTemplate<T extends ApiTemplate>(template: T) {
  return template;
}
```

Then define the object as an argument to the function:

```js
const apiConfig1 = assertTemplate({
  func1: {
    call: (count: number) => console.log("count", count),
    handler: (data: any) => console.log(data),
  },
  func2: {
    call: (name: string) => console.log(name),
    handler: (data: any) => console.log("string", data),
  },
  func3: { // <-- errors here saying 'call' is missing
    handler: (data: any) => console.log("any", data)
  }
});
```

However, I wish I understood why there isn't a more direct way to do this.